# C# Animations (Sliders, etc.)

Tags: c#

I have yet to get into C# Animations and i'm still learning some of the basics in beginners C# and I'd love to learn animations!
So what I need is the move my panel1 from X: -4 ; Y:-50   to X:-4 ; Y:27
I don't want it to go too fast or too slow.

I need examples of ways to plot this animations the drop in and out when selected
(Down button: button1) ; (Up button: button2) So I'll need a setup to fit in those areas!

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //this is the panel i need to move from X:-4 Y:27 to X:-4 Y:-50
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //panel1 down
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //panel1 up
    }
}
```

}

Comment: are you using WPF?

Comment: i'm using Visual Studios 2017

Comment: I am not asking visual studio version. May be you have taken Winform Application in Visual Studio. Animations can be done in WPF Application and even you can control with C#.